# Example of a K3 surface where the Picard group is generated by a single elliptic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, k3-surfaces

In a paper by Voisin[1] she considers as an example a K3-surface whose Picard group is generated by the class of an elliptic curve.

> ... l'exemple d'une surface K3 dont le groupe de Picard est engendré par la classe d'une courbe elliptique ...

What would be a concrete example of such a K3 surface?

A surface $S \subset \mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb  P^2$ of bidegree $(2,3)$ gives an elliptic fibration $S \to \mathbb P^1$, so there are plenty elliptic curves, all linearly equivalent, but according to [2, Example 5.8] the Picard group still has rank $2$.

[1] Claire Voisin, *Surt la stabilité des sous-variétés lagrangiennes*.

[2] Bert van Geemen, *Some remarks on Brauer groups of K3 surfaces*

Comment: Projective $K3$ surfaces can not be examples, since self-intersection of an elliptic curve is zero.

Comment: @Mohan Why is self-intersection $0$ not possible?

Comment: If Pic is generated by such a curve, we see that all line bundles have self-intersection zero, so no ample line bundle.

Comment: @Mohan I thought a non-algebraic K3 surface doesn't contain any curves? (Probably I am misremembering.)

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I was making no statement about non-algebraic surfaces. Just that such surfaces OP wants can not be projective.

Comment: @Mohan Hm, according to Wikipedia (which cites Huybrechts) algebraic K3 surfaces are automatically projective. So we are only left with non-algebraic ones.